# How to get the name of the app by position?

Tags: java, android, reverse-engineering

I am just creating a quick application in which there would be a floating icon on the home and the user have to just drag and drop that icon to the app and then it will show a alert window.

I know how to create the floating icon using some maths and windowmanager but don't know how should i get the name of the app on which the floating icon is dropped. I have thought of some ways to archive this, but don't know how to implement it....

By Getting the position of the touch when ACTION_UP Trigger is occurred and then checking what's the app is by comparing it with its position.

But there is a problem in this way, because i don't know how to get the position of launching icons on the homepage.

Help me to archive this task. Please tell me How can i get the position of launching icon(like facebook, google play) on the homepage .  Also it would be very helpful if you can suggest me other ways of doing this.

> I know this can be done because winners of techcrunch hackathon have
>   made the same application. A short video of this can be found here, in
>   case you might want to look,
>   http://techcrunch.com/2015/09/20/disrupt-sf-2015-hackathon-winners/

Answer (score 1):

> i don't know how to get the position of launching icons on the homepage.

That is not possible in general, outside of perhaps the accessibility APIs.

Please bear in mind that there are > 1 billion Android devices in use. Those span thousands of device models, representing hundreds or thousands of home screen implementations. Users can also install third-party home screen implementations (e.g., from the Play Store) and use those.

There is no requirement that a home screen have "launching icons" that meet your expectations. I could write a home screen whose app launcher consisted of text hyperlinks, for example. Or, I could write a home screen that is designed to be used by an external keyboard, where launching apps is triggered by keypresses rather than icons.

There is no requirement that a home screen have some sort of API that, given some X/Y coordinate on some arbitrary piece of that home screen, would tell you an app that is represented by something visual at that X/Y coordinate.

You are welcome to try using the accessibility APIs to find details of a widget at the desired X/Y coordinate on the current screen. However, from there, you would have to make guesses as to whether or not that is a launcher icon and, if so, what app it would represent. This approach is likely to be unreliable, except for specific scenarios that you have hard-coded. Hard-coding is what the team you cited appears to have done, based on the prose on the TechCrunch site.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is there a way that someone can get the screenshot of the homepage

Comment: @Hudixt: On Android 5.0+, you can use the media projection APIs for this, though the user has to agree, via a pop-up window, to allow your app to take screenshots. However, you have no good way of knowing that "the homepage" is in the foreground, and the various hacks for trying to get this information are continually being broken, for privacy and security reasons.